# Breaking a "for" loop using "break" considered harmful?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, goto, break

Some days ago I started a quick open source project and, when some mates looked at the code on svn, one of them told me that using `break` statement inside a `for` loop is considered harmful and shouldn't be done.

He added, though, that I would find several cases of `break` statements inside `for` loops on Linux kernel source code, but that was just because only Linus Torvalds and Chuck Norris were allowed to use it and no one else.

What do you think? I see no problem in using `break` inside a `for` loop. In my opinion, emulating the behaviour of `break` using boolean variables or something alike adds a lot of innecesary overhead and makes the code less straightforward.

Also, there's no room for comparison with `goto`, because `break` cannot arbitrarily change program's flow from one point to the other lie `goto` does.

Comment: I think `continue` is considered "harmful" though, in the same league as "goto" (both can be useful, but both can obscure code). `break` looks fine to me though, personally.

Comment: I use `break` very often, and `continue` quite often as well. I think that -- and the same things applies to multiple exists, Delphi `while` statements, etc., etc. -- that in most cases when someone says "don't use the X construct", then he/she is is not very used to writing complex algorithms and/or that he/she is not very experienced in the language at hand. Because, if one is very experienced at the language at hand, then one knows how to use this construct, and if one often writes complex algorithms, then one will love all these constructs.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: The "Possible Duplicate" link is dead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I see no problem with using breaks. There will always be circumstances where you want to stop processing a loop, and using a `break;` makes much more sense (and makes it more readable!) than setting your loop counter up to a value that would make your loop stop at the next iteration.

Comment: I see no proble with using goto. There will always be circumstances where you want to stop processing a very nested loop, and using goto; makes more sense (and makes it more readable!) than having boolean values to tell you when to get out of the loops.

Answer (score 41):

Obligatory:

[image: XKCD Goto]

The point is that you should not avoid it purely on grounds of bad practice (or velociraptors), but consider on a case by case basis.

It's all about clarity.  As you said, you never have to use it, but in some cases it promotes readability.  It's useful when the loop usually terminates normally, but in rare cases you have to bail out.  Loops that usually (or always) break are more of a code smell (but could still be appropriate).

Comment: +1 for providing a good answer with this comic. I recall seeing one heavily upvoted answer that was this comic and nothing else, ugh.

Answer (score 22):

Not only is there no problem to using `break`, I'd say anyone saying it is "considered harmful" is downright wrong.

`break` is a language feature used to abort a loop - you could use `goto`, but then you incur the (appropriate) wrath of the XKCD comic below. You could use a flag in the condition, but that hampers readability. `break` is not only the easiest, but also the clearest way many times to bust out of a loop. Use it as it was meant to be used.

---

*Edit:* To get at a larger picture here: When you're writing code, the guiding principle to "should I use language feature X or Y" should be "which way will result in the more elegant code"? Elegance, in code, is pretty much an art, but I'd lay it down as a fine balance between readability and algorithmic (read: not micro-optimizations) efficiency. Readability is going to be determined by length, complexity of the code, etc. A one-line boost::bind may very well be harder to read & understand than a 3 line loop.

If a language feature can help you write code that is easier to understand while getting the job done, then use it. This applies to `break`, `goto`, C++ exceptions, etc. Don't follow a "X is (evil|considered harmful)" blindly - apply common sense and logic each time.

Answer (score 12):

Not only is there no problem with `break`, it's also [OK to use `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050129/will-the-compiler-optimize-escaping-an-inner-loop/3050138#3050138) when `break` is insufficient. Don't be afraid of multiple returns, either.

**All of the above only applies if it makes the code easier to understand*.**

*And if your [PHB](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PointyHairedBoss) allows it...

Answer (score 8):

I think your mate is insane.  `break` is perfectly acceptable, perfectly readable, and perfectly maintainable.  Period.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paradigm that any loop should only have one point of exit (same as a function should only have one return). This has to do with readability. Too many exit points can make the code very difficult to understand. Also, it is important if you want to do code verification (i.e. mathematically proof if your code is correct).

However, guidelines are often there to help, but are not strict. There are possibly situations where a break is better than not using it. Hence, one should be pragmatic about this, but understand the reason for such principles in order to create good code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on context. While it may be 'bad' coding style in some situations, I can't think of a case where it would be *harmful*.

In fact, in some cases I would recommend it. For example, if you were using a linear search, <strike>any case (except the very worst case), a `break` would improve your speed.</strike> I think breaking out of the loop when you've found your needle would be perfectly acceptable, and it would be more readable than messing around with the loop variable (which might not solely be used for the loop, depending on your program) or wrapping the loop body in an `if` block. (And the other option, an `if` which contains `continue`, combines the worst of two worlds: wrapping loop logic in an `if` block, and the poor coding style railed against by people like your friends who don't like `break`.)

Comment: You should not recommend break on performance grounds. Compilers can usually optimise status variables.

Comment: Fair point. The point I was trying to make was if, for example, I'm performing a linear search on a large number of elements and I find what I'm looking for at index 2, I would much prefer to stop looking than continue looping over the remaining elements which I know I don't want.

On the other hand, if I know I'll have a large number of elements, I probably wouldn't go for linear search, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing your loop counter instead of using break also means you finish executing the current iteration of the loop, which may or may not be desirable.
Of course, you could wrap the rest of it in an `if` clause, and then do it again when you realize you need to check whether or not to stop looping multiple times, and you will quickly realize why people use `break;`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this algorithm if you're considering using a given technique.

- If it is considered **good practice**:

  - use it.
- If it is **not** considered good practice:

  - use it only if you judge it to be the best long-term solution.
- If it is considered **evil**:

  - use it only if you judge it to be the best long-term solution and you are extremely confident in your judgement. Beware: things which are considered evil tend to be deceptively appealing.

I would classify `break;` as "not good practice". Use it when it makes the code more readable, reduces the chance of bugs, does not complicate debugging, etc.